# How to get CSS Modules to work with Reactstrap cssModule propType?

Tags: reactjs, reactstrap, react-css-modules

I noticed most form elements in the Reactstrap documentation have a PropType of a cssModule. I would assume that means I could override the default Reactstrap styles and do something like this:

**Formtext.module.css**

```
.formtext {
  background-color: blue;
  border: 2px solid black;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

**SimpleForm.jsx**

```
import styles from "./Formtext.module.css";
...

<FormText cssModule={styles.formtext}>
   This is some placeholder help text...
</FormText>
```

```

However, this doesn't seem to work.  Checking my react dev tools the cssModule prop evaluates to `undefined`.

I'm using Using Reactstrap 5.0 and create-react-app 1.1.5

Is there something I'm unaware of that I need to do?
Do I need to eject to be able to use css-modules?
Can someone point me to an example of how to use the Reactstrap's cssModule prop correctly?

---

For reference here is the proptypes definition from Reactstrap docs

```
FormText.propTypes = {
  children: PropTypes.node,
  inline: PropTypes.bool,
  tag: PropTypes.oneOfType([PropTypes.func, PropTypes.string]), // default: 'small'
  color: PropTypes.string, // default: 'muted'
  className: PropTypes.string,
  cssModule: PropTypes.object,
};
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### On cssModule

It looks like cssModules doesn't behave quite like you would think; the prop doesn't take a single, overriding class - it takes a rejected class and a replacement class.

Reactstrap uses mapToCssModules to get this done. See its documentation [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/map-to-css-modules). Take note of the usage example:

```
<Example tag="div" cssModule={{ 'w-100': 'w-75' }} />
```

So your case would look something like this:

```
<FormText cssModule={{ 'form-text' : styles.formtext }} />
```

This will *completely* surpress the 'form-text' class though (which in your case, only contributes `display: block`. If you'd like to override more selectively, see below.

---

### Try this instead

In the [FormText source code](https://github.com/reactstrap/reactstrap/blob/0e4e9fb59b4df678d506d95f73314792dbed2e82/src/FormText.js#L30-L38), it looks like you may be able to do your overrides in a different way:

- If you want to omit the `form-text` class altogether, include `inline` as a prop,
- If you want to omit any color-related bootstrap classes, set 'color' to `false` (or something `falsy`),
- set the `className` prop to your CSS Module object (`styles.formtext`).

`<FormText className={styles.formText} color='' inline>
  Test formtext
</FormText>`

The most important part here is actually the `className` prop. You can also further override styling by including a `tag` prop (again, check the FormText docs).

---

#### Hope this was helpful! Happy holidays!

Answer (score 3):

I did not really get the accepted answer, but I had the same problem recently and in my opinion, `cssModule` behaves exactly as one would expect.
You just pass an imported module object and then specify classes they will be referenced towards the module.

Here is my example (from create-react-app) how I did fix Navbar to get it's bootstrap styles from my bootstrap module (as I don't import bootstrap globally):

```
import cx from 'classnames';
import bootstrap from 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
import navbar from './navbar.css';

let styles = Object.assign({}, bootstrap, navbar);

public render() {
    return (<Navbar cssModule={styles} className={cx(styles.navbarExpandSm, styles.navbarToggleableSm, styles.borderBottom, styles.boxShadow, styles.mb3)} light>[your menu here]</Navbar>);
}
```

This simply says the control to take the styles module and reference all the class names passed in classNames towards it. If you take a look at the `mapToCssModules` method, it is exactly what it does.
https://github.com/reactstrap/reactstrap/blob/d3cd4ea79dcaf478af5984f760ff1290406f62a5/src/utils.js#L53

In my case, it allows the control to pick up the original bootstrap styles and I can override what I need in my own module.